# kivy run_on_ui_thread crash

Tags: python, kivy, pyjnius

The application compiles without problems, but when the application is executed it closes

version:

kivi - 1.10.0
cython: 0.28.6
python: 3.7.1

main.py

```py
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from jnius import autoclass
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread


WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')
activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity


class Wv(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Wv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_webview, 0)

    @run_on_ui_thread
    def create_webview(self, *args):
        pass

class ServiceApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Wv()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServiceApp().run()
```

this is error:

```
Attribute error: 'Wv' object has no attribute 'f2'
```

Comment: Is this all your code? Also post the full traceback.

Comment: yes, this is all the code, the problem is in the decorator "run_on_ui_thread" that is in the android module in runnable.py https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/develop/pythonforandroid/ recipes / android / src / android / runnable.py but I do not understand why this error happens, only this error happens if I inherit from widget

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Get that `create_webview` out of the class and it'll work fine. Since you're using the decorator on a class method, it's searching for `f2` within the class itself.